# why does it not printing the count value?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have one Main class which is:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Processor p=new Processor();
        Thread t1=new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    p.produce();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        t1.start();
        
        Thread t2=new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    p.consume();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        System.out.println("count : "+p.count); 
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Processor {
    Queue<Integer> q=new LinkedList<>();
    int count=0;
    public void produce() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(this) {
            for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
            {
                count++;
                System.out.println("produced : "+i);
                q.add(i);
                wait();
            }
        }
        
    }
    public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        while(true) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if(q.size()!=0) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("consumed : "+q.poll());
                    notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

basically whatever values the producer produces, consumer consumes it.
It gives the expected output in case of Producer and consumer but why does it not print the count value?

Comment: You have a while (true) in your consume method. You need to break it or add a better condition

Answer (score 2):

in this line:

```
t2.join();
```

you are waiting for a thread that will never terminate because of the `while (true)` loop in the `consume` method